# Can I use MongoDB for an ActiveMQ Master/Slave architecture?

Tags: java, mongodb, jms, activemq-classic, master-slave

I want to set up an [ActiveMQ Master/Slave cluster](http://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-master-slave.html)
If I understand correctly (please correct me if I'm wrong), this needs a JDBC supporting database like MySql, and this is only for synchronisation purposes.

The thing is, I already have a MongoDB cluster in place, so I'd like to avoid having to install another DB. Is it possible to use MongoDB or something else already available?

Comment: Don't you just need to configure a datasource with the proper driver? I know this one but I didn't use it http://sourceforge.net/projects/mongojdbcdriver/?source=navbar

Comment: I hardly think that would work. That "JDBC" driver seems very limited "Each row has two columns (ObjectId and Document)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you do Master/Slave with ActiveMQ is to keep the persistence store some place shared. While it work with most major databases using plain JDBC, it still requires features like table lock to figure out which server is the master. There are no JDBC/SQL drivers for MongoDB that I am aware of that can handle this properly.

The recommended approach to ActiveMQ Master/Slave is to use a shared disk area somewhere for persistency (SAN or similar). The JDBC approach is very slow, even with SQL database servers.

And - NO. The database is not for synchronization only. Every persistent message will be written to it.

**Update**

As of ActiveMQ 5.9.0 there is also a [clustered approach](http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html) available which uses LevelDB.